# Login to the other Website using ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

i tried many times using httprequest but not working...
here my code

```
//POSTDATA=inputUserName=dmsang&inputPassword=123456789
string strURL;
string strPostData = "";
string strResult;
HttpWebResponse webrespond;
HttpWebRequest webresquest;
StreamReader sr;
StreamWriter sw;

//======================================

//string a = form1.FindControl("chogochu");

//set url to post
strURL = "http://up.4share.vn/?act=login";

//post some data        
strPostData = "inputUserName=dmsang&inputPassword=123456789";

webresquest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL);
webresquest.Method = "POST";
webresquest.Referer = strURL;
webresquest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webresquest.ContentLength = strPostData.Length;

//post data
sw = new StreamWriter(webresquest.GetRequestStream());
sw.Write(strPostData);
sw.Close();

//read the returned data
webrespond = (HttpWebResponse)webresquest.GetResponse();
sr = new StreamReader(webrespond.GetResponseStream());
strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();

//write the result
TextBox1.Text = strResult;
```

if Location in Response Header = /?act=accinfo is Login Successful

Answer (score 0):

You will have to examine the response (`strResult` and `webrespond.Headers`) to see what the error is.  The problem should be shown somewhere in there, and what you find will determine what step you need to take next.

Comment: i tried this: http://www.netomatix.com/httppostdata.aspx
but the form login in Client side it's mean it's open a new tab and send login informations, i want to Code login in Server Side so that Client can't view my password account...

Comment: @Raito _ I don't think you read my answer very carefuly. After your program reads the http response, _you_ the programmer (not your code) must actually read the html code sent back (via the debugger or log), and possibly examine the headers as well, until you see what the web server is telling you the error is so that you can adjust your code to account for the error.